# Xpath returning null values for elements under <header> tag

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome Extension using vanilla JavaScript to hide sections of the page depending on the user type.  The user type is in the  section of the page.  I can access elements outside the  tag, but nothing within the tag.

I have tried using the span ID with '//*[@id="userType"]' but this returns null.  I have also tried to access other elements within the header (other  or  elements) and I was not able to access those either.  I can only access elements outside of the  tag.

html page code:

```
<body>
  <form id="form1">
    <header>
      <div>
        <span onclick="DP$LinkButton$Click(this, null, null, 'file.asp',null); return(false);
          <span id="userType">user1</span>
          <span id="userName">Bob</span>
        </span>
     </div>
    </header>
    <div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

xPath function:

```
function getElementByXpath(path) {
  // returns the element value matching the Xpath
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue; 
} // end function getElementByXpath
```

xPath tests:

```
console.log(getElementByXpath('//*[@id="userType"]'));
console.log(getElementByXpath('//*[contains(@id,"userType")]'));
console.log(document.getElementById('userType'));
console.log(getElementByXpath("/html/body/form/header/div/span/span[@id='userType']"));
```

All xPath queries returned 'null'.  I tried the console.log on the xPath using .text(), .innerHTML, blank, or just the entire header and it returned 'null'.  My xPath function works perfectly fine on other elements that are outside the header tag.  Help please!

Comment: 1) The `<span` tag isn't closed in your code - is it a copypaste artifact or that's a problem with the page? 2) The behavior you've described is typical for dynamic sites that populate the content using their script, on which case you need a MutationObserver or another listener, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508954), 3) If it's inside ShadowDOM you need to look inside the header's shadowRoot.

Comment: The unclosed <span tag was a copy/paste effect--I was trying to pull the essentials out to post. Sorry!  You are correct - this is a dynamic site - but it is strange that I can pull the other elements on the page (the main body of the page), but not items in the header element.  I will look into the MutationObserver and ShadowDOM.  Thanks! edited for spelling...

Comment: I looked into the MutationObserver and ShadowDOM, but that didn't work (but I am new to those so I may not have used them correctly).  What I did find was that if the user refreshes the page, the above xpath queries do work, but if they just use the navigation bar to change the main area of the page, it did not.  To solve, I instituted a global variable to hold the usertype from when they first logged in/refreshed the page, and not change it if it is null.